# What's with the flip?

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking, story, computer-science, information-theory

Uh-oh... We should've taken Professor Kernighan's advice before taking this trip and learned the local language. This desert is dreadful and we just want to reach civilization again, as fast as possible. We're stuck at a fork in the road, but we have no idea which way to travel...

To the left, we see a sign with the following information:

> ### ↯⠞⠶⠶⇻❃⇻━ ☥⇕
>
> #### 153 ◉ 152 ◉ 151 ◉ 144 ◉ ...

To the right, there's another sign, with the following information:

> ### ↯⠒⠶⠶⇻✺⇻━ ☥↡
>
> #### 63 ◉ 62 ◉ 61 ◉ 59 ◉ ...

Richard, you're the expert... Which path is the shortest route to civilization?

##### Hints

> The distance between the tops of the signs is 3.

Comment: In retrospect, I hope this isn't *too* enigmatic. I want to avoid the need for the [tag:enigmatic-puzzle] tag here.

Comment: Do the "..." indicate that the signs have more text than reproduced here, or is "..." literally written on the signs?

Comment: @2012rcampion it's literally written on the signs, but it seems to imply the presence of a sequence.